# testing function in python that need to get input from user and print the output, using pycharm and pytest

Tags: python, testing, pycharm, subprocess, pytest

I wrote code in python 3, and want to write tests to my code using the Pytest framework. 
I have one function (the main function) that gets input from the user(a file name), processes it and prints a result to the screen(the answer can be true or false).
How can I write a test function that inputs data by herself(for the main input) and check what printed to the console? (I use Pycharm)

Comment: I meant that my test-function will feed the input that the main wait to get,
and the test function will read what the main printed to the console and will know to say if the output was good or not

Answer (score 0):

```py
def main():
    file_input = input(str('path to your file here'))
    with open(file_input, mode="r") as f:
        for line in f:
            reader = line.split()
            # Convert to boolean <-- Not working?
            flag = bool(reader[0])

            if flag:
                print('flag == True')
            else:
                print('flag == False')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I meant that my test-function will feed the input that the main wait to get, and the test function will read what the main printed to the console and will know to say if the output was good or not